# How to fix - TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Tags: python

Here is my code -

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence without punctuation")
sentence = sentence.lower()
words = sentence.split()
pos = [words.index(s)+1 for s in words]
hi = print("This sentence can be recreated from positions", pos)
print(hi)

saveFile = open("exampleFile.txt" , "w")
saveFile.write(hi)
saveFile.close()
```

However i get the error - TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
and im not sure how to fix it

Comment: `print` returns `None`, why are you assigning its result?

Comment: So.. did I answer your question?

Comment: well, you are writing this None. At last you try... `write(hi)` equals `write(None)`. You most probably want to do `write(pos)`

Comment: What's the other way?

Comment: No, it's not. One says `... not None`, the other says `... not list`

Comment: Sorry wrong answer what i meant to say was that it doesn't work either way , they both return errors :( Ty for trying to help

Comment: I think il try converting the list into string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write('+'.join([str(x) for x in pos])) should work for you.`

Replace the `+` with whatever delimiter you want.

Similar to your original code line `[words.index(s)+1 for s in words]` this list comprehension is a short form of a loop.

It takes every element in pos, names it x and applies the function str(x). The result of str(x) is then added to a new list.

So `[1234]` is converted to a new list `['1','2','3','4']`. 
Finally '+'.join(new list) joins all elements using `'+'` as delimiter.
So we end up with the string `1+2+3+4`. 
Note how this seems the same as above, but now it's characters, not numbers anymore.

The string is than the final parameter so python 'sees' write('1+2+3+4').

Comment: So I guess it was you voting this answer as _not_ helpful? ;)

Comment: Never mind! I was just confused. You can however unvote and revote AFAIK.